# Basis Definition clarity

Tags: general-topology

For $\mathcal{B}$ to be a basis of some topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$, my book says:

1) For each $x \in X$, there is at least one basis element $B \in \mathcal{B}$ containing $x$.

2) If 
$x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then there exists a $B_3$ containing $x$ s.t. $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

However, someone told me the following was equivalent: 
    'For $\mathcal{B}$ to be a basis, we must check that the sets of $\mathcal{B}$ cover $X$ and the intersection of any two subsets of $\mathcal{B}$ can be written as a union of some of them'.

Are these two definitions indeed equivalent? Particularly, is "the intersection of any two subsets of $\mathcal{B}$ can be written as a union of some of them" equivalent to "If 
$x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ then there exists $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $ B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$"

Comment: The definition of a basis you have is incorrect, point 2 should be: "If $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, there is a $B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$ such that $x\in B_3$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that is what I had meant to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement (1) implies that the basis elements cover $X$. Conversely, if the basis elements cover $X$, each point of $X$ is contained in [at least] one of the basis elements.

Statement (2) implies that the intersection of two basis elements is the union of basis elements: for each $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, choose a basis element $B_x$ such that $x \in B_x \subset B_1 \cap B_2$. Then $B_1 \cap B_2 = \bigcup_{x \in B_1 \cap B_2} B_x$. Conversely, if the intersection of two basis elements is a union of basis elements, then each element in the intersection is contained in [at least] one of the basis elements in the union, each of which are contained in $B_1 \cap B_2$.

Comment: This answer becomes correct once statement 2 in the question is corrected as pointed out in Mike Earnest's comment.